# Embedded scripting language with C/C++ API for multithreading environment

Tags: c++, python, c, scripting, lua

I'm looking for an embedded scripting language.

I don't need anything fancy, just basic constructs like conditionals, loops, logic and arithmetic operations etc.

I have the following requirements

1. Thread friendly - i.e. without "global interpreter lock" (python is out for this reason)
2. Cheap "interpreter instance" creation - I will have potentially 100s of these. I understand that lua creates a separate gc thread per every `Lua_State` which means lua is out.
3. No gc or refcounting or any other "on the fly" memory management. It should simply destroy any variables once the script is executed. Again both python and lua are out.
4. And of course it should be fast and have low memory footprint.
5. Should work on windows, GNU/Linux and MacOS X

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it will be extremely hard to find a modern scripting language without a GC or refcounted memory model. I would personally recommend Google v8 - but then there is the question of threading. You can run scripts in separate threads concurrently with Isolates, but you can't share anything JavaScript'ish between them. Hence they are Isolate'd.

Answer (score 7):

Reconsider Lua:

1. Yes.
2. Yes. Lua does not create any OS threads at all.
3. Garbage collection does not start until you've created lots of objects. You can simply turn it off. To destroy all variables once the script is executed, simply close the state.
4. Yes.
5. Yes.

Comment: 2. On current OSes, native threads are very lightweight. It then depends on what runs underneath...

Comment: Does closing the state ensure finalizers are called? I always wondered about that.

Comment: @Cubic, yes, it does. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_close .